# Add an rtf file to a RichEditControl from Resources

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm tying to load an .rtf file, which is inside Resources. and add it to a RichEditControl

This is the code I tried:

```
private void RetardPret_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (Stream stream = GetResourceStream("GestionBib.Properties.Resources.s.rtf"))
    {
      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      richEditControl1.LoadDocument(stream, DocumentFormat.Rtf);
      stream.Close();
    }
}

static Stream GetResourceStream(string resourceName)
{
  return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
}
```

But I had an error in this line `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Check if the file exists (File.exists()), else your stream will be null. Your path for the stream might be wrong.

Comment: Like this : File.Exists("GestionBib.Properties.Resources.s.rtf") ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the 3rd party rich text control you are using, but this is an example of what works for just the standard RichTextBox control from Microsoft (no error checking):

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = Properties.Resources.s;
```

Note: When directly referencing a resource, the extension gets dropped off.  Also, I went straight to the Rtf property, not the LoadFile (or LoadDocument in your case).